# the output of getText method cant be stored in the String variable, what to do?

Tags: java, android, gettext

**i am having trouble with storing the data in variable  from getText method it's returning the data but variable is not storing the data if i put the et1.getText.toString in the toast in stead  of variable its working i dont know why this happening please help out**

```
    package com.example.mad_lab_one_addition_app;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import android.os.Bundle;
    //import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        EditText et1,et2;
        Button btn;
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            et1 = findViewById(R.id.edittextone);
            et2 = findViewById(R.id.edittexttwo);
            btn = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    
            add();
        }
    
        public void add(){
    
    
            String string = et1.getText().toString();
            // String str2 = et2.getText().toString();
    
    //        int a = Integer.parseInt(str);
    //        int b = Integer.parseInt(str2);
    //        int c = a+b;
    
    
    
            btn.setOnClickListener(v -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,string,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
    
        }
    }
    </code>
    </pre>


it is java file !
```

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittextone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_first_number"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/edittexttwo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:importantForAutofill="no" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittexttwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="218dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_second_number"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
        android:text="@string/add"
        app:backgroundTint="@null"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edittexttwo" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

its XMl !
i am trying to print a toast but its printing empty toast.
can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `EditText` is empty at the first. you should enter the text in the `EditText` then click the button and store the data into the variable.
please follow this approach:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText et1,et2;
    Button btn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et1 = findViewById(R.id.edittextone);
        et2 = findViewById(R.id.edittexttwo);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(v ->
                String temp = et1.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,temp,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());

                // Do whatever you want with the temp.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should always check if the **EditText** is empty or not before getting value from it
if you are trying to achieve some simple addition like c=a+b, you can check this code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText et1,et2;
    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        et1 = findViewById(R.id.edittextone);
        et2 = findViewById(R.id.edittexttwo);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.button1);


        btn.setOnClickListener(v ->{
            String num1 = et1.getText().toString();
            String num2 = et1.getText().toString();

            if(num1.isEmpty() || num2.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter a and b", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
             add(Integer.parseInt(num1),Integer.parseInt(num2));
            }
        });


    }
    public void add(int a,int b){
        int c = a+b;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Result "+c, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

also if you are doing additions using numbers change your EditText input type to number in xml

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer ,I didn't used the same code you answered , but your answer helped me to get  understand the actual problem and I got the solution.
           the problem is that when the activity starts the value of et1 and et2 is set to null by compiler, and when i clicks the button the function is working with null value ,so i put the value fetching sentances in the onclick method so its fetching the value after the click.

thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just Initialize your variable , here we will set its initial value `null`. Then everything would be fine .Nothing to do more. This will solve your problem.

```
EditText et1 = null;
EditText et2 = null;
```

If you want to know more just follow step otherwise not.
If you want to show Toast on Activity Create just make the `add` method `runnable`.

```
 public void add(final String string){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    }
```

If you want to show by button click then -

```
btn.setOnClickListener(v -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,string,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
```

Your MainActivity-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText et1 = null;
    EditText et2 = null;

    Button btn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et1 = findViewById(R.id.edittextone);
        et2 = findViewById(R.id.edittexttwo);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.button1);

     //   add();
        String string = et1.getText().toString();
        //without user action
        add(string);
     //with user action
        btn.setOnClickListener(v -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,string,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());

    }

    public void add(final String string){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Zahis islam but this is still not working , also i reinstalled the android studio latest  and created the new project but still its not working.

Comment: I have changed two lines of code EditText et1 = null;
    EditText et2 = null; did you notice?